# VS Code throws me to settings.json when trying to compile c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation

I can't compile any c++ code in VS Code. Whenever I try, it throws me to the settings.json file, where I see this:

```
{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Pavel Sankin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python.exe",
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Pavel Sankin\\Anaconda3"
}
```

and nothing else. I did install the standard C/C++ extension and tried checking out the official website for help, but there seem to be other things there. VS Code doesn't throw any errors, it just opens this file whenever I try to compile any piece of C++ code.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: And what are python interpreter settings supposed to do when compiling C++?

Comment: VS Code is a text editor, not an IDE. The extension will only work if you have installed a C++ environment it can use.

Comment: I did install the C++ environement, as I mentioned in the question. And about Python, I genuanly have no idea on what it's doing there. I did install it too, but it shouldn't pop up when compiling C++. I'm confused myself

Comment: @Mokrall, No you didn't. You installed the C/C++ extension, which is NOT a C++ environment. You need to install the C++ build tools (or MinGW) if on Windows, or XCode if on a Mac, or whatever required packages if on Linux. Like I said the the extension **only works if you have installed a C++ environment**. Your question text mentions literally NOTHING about a C++ environment. VS Code isn't one, and neither is the the extension. I explained this. If you're coming here for help, you should probably try trusting us when we tell you something.

Comment: @sweenish ok I got it now. I have CodeBlocks and VS Studio installed though. They include MinGW and the gcc and g++ compilers. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Did you tell the extension what compiler to use? Where the include directories are? VS Code with MS tools requires launching it from a special shell, per their documentation. I doubt CodeBlocks added MinGW to your PATH.

Comment: @sweenish ok thanks a lot man now I'll try to do that

Comment: Can't believe the first time I install VSC, this same stupid bug pops. And I had no idea why this renowned software is so troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had this problems before?
Have you install the microsoft C++ compiler toolset? (other compiler works fine too; check VS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019))
Did you open VSCode using the Developer Command Prompt?

Also check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) and follow the guide.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @sweenish yup, just got past 50 points in order to access comment section

Comment: Lack of points is not a valid excuse for posting comments as answers. Instead of validating your point count, delete this answer and move it to a comment.